# flutter based wayland compositor like qtwayland

Tags: flutter, wayland, qtwayland

Using Qt, we can make compositor server on embedded system. Recently I'm considering flutter new app framework to make system UI on embedded device. But, I can't find appropriate solution for compositor server like qtwayland.

Anyone knows some solution for building flutter wayland compositor server ?

I'm checking two options, but it looks performance is not good and I'm not sure wlroot is maintained.

https://github.com/roscale/zenith
https://github.com/PlayPulseCom/flutter_wlroots